# nodejs and socket io sync issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm new to nodejs and socket io thing, but I'm really trying to understand how this works. I've already completed the "chat tutorial" from the socket io website. However, I'm trying to do something "new" here. Each time a new connection is established, I want to broadcast an event to all clients, by appending a new tab with a random number. However, the only things that happens, is that it appends once (on my own connection) but nothing to others? Is this not possible, or am i just doing it the wrong way?

Server,

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use("/assets/stylesheets", express.static(__dirname + '/assets/stylesheets'));
app.use("/assets/javascripts", express.static(__dirname + '/assets/javascripts'));
app.use("/assets/demo/avatars", express.static(__dirname + '/assets/demo/avatars'));
app.use("/assets/fonts/font-awesome/", express.static(__dirname + '/assets/fonts/font-awesome/'));

app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dashboard.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.on('new user', function(username) {
        socket.emit('new connection', { nickname: username });
        console.log('new connection ' + username);
    });

});

http.listen(3000,function() {
    console.log('Listening *:3000');
});
```

Client,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

    var socket = io();

    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.emit('new user', randomNumber);
    });

    socket.on('new connection', function(data) {
        var nickname = data.nickname;
        $('<li class="active"> <a href="#' + nickname + '" data-toggle="tab">' + nickname + '<span class="label label-success">12</span></a> </li>').appendTo("#uidemo-tabs-default-demo");
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep a list of all the open connections on the server and then, when a new connection occurs, send messages to all the other connections.

Here is modified code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var connections = [];

app.use("/assets/stylesheets", express.static(__dirname + '/assets/stylesheets'));
app.use("/assets/javascripts", express.static(__dirname + '/assets/javascripts'));
app.use("/assets/demo/avatars", express.static(__dirname + '/assets/demo/avatars'));
app.use("/assets/fonts/font-awesome/", express.static(__dirname + '/assets/fonts/font-awesome/'));

app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dashboard.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.on('new user', function(username) {
        connections.forEach(function (socket) {
            try {
                socket.emit('new connection', { nickname: username });
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('connection probably closed: ', err);
            }
        });
        console.log('new connection ' + username);
        connections.push(socket);
    });

});

http.listen(3000,function() {
    console.log('Listening *:3000');
});
```

However, be aware that this will only work if your Node.js server only has one instance (i.e. you are not using the `cluster` module), more work will be required to get it to work in a cluster and even more if it must work in a redundant infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `socket.broadcast.emit` to broadcast..

```
socket.on('new user', function(username) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('new connection', { nickname: username });
    console.log('new connection ' + username);
});
```

However this will not send the message to your own connection but to all other connections. If you want to send the message to all connections including yourself,

```
socket.on('new user', function(username) {
    socket.emit('new connection', { nickname: username });
    socket.broadcast.emit('new connection', { nickname: username });
    console.log('new connection ' + username);
});
```